# What script to write on receiving file?

Tags: php, ios, cordova, file-transfer

I have created a script  that takes a photo and transfers it to a remote server by follow the tutorial [here](http://metabates.com/2012/04/15/capturing-and-uploading-photos-on-ios-with-phonegap/). This seems to be working, but I am very unsure about what to write on the recieving end of the this script, ie: what I need to put on my php file on my server.

Ultimately, I would like to write the image to a directory on the server and then save its path to a database.

Would anyone know what function(s) I should look for, to do this? I cannot find anything in the Cordova manuals and am pretty lost as to what to do.

Should I just be using PHPs `GET` or `REQUEST` functions?

(I am creating an app for iOS in XCode)

My code is:

```
     smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI;

              var fail, ft, options, params, win;
              // callback for when the photo has been successfully uploaded:
              var success =  function(response) {
                  alert("Photo Saved");
              };
              // callback if the photo fails to upload successfully.
              var fail = function(error) {
                  alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
                  alert(FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR);
              };
              options = new FileUploadOptions();
              // parameter name of file:
              options.fileKey = "my_image";
              // name of the file:
              options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
              // mime type:
              options.mimeType = "text/plain";
              params = {
                  val1: "some value",
                  val2: "some other value"
              };
              options.params = params;
              ft = new FileTransfer();
              ft.upload(imageURI, 'http://mysite.com/appimages/recieve.php', success, fail, options);
```

(NB: recieve.php is currently blank)

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @SunilMishra almost I think, though I can return the files info, it is not writing it to the directory

Comment: Make sure the directory exists and has permission to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to save the uploaded file

```
<?php
$target_path = "tmp/";
if ($_FILES["my_image"]["error"] > 0){
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["my_image"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else{ 
    if (file_exists($target_path . $_FILES["my_image"]["name"])){
        echo $_FILES["my_image"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    }
    else{
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["my_image"]["tmp_name"], $target_path . $_FILES["my_image"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . $target_path . $_FILES["my_image"]["name"];
    }
}
?>
```